# inactive ? @"inactive": @"active" syntax?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Can someone explain the `inactive ? @"inactive": @"active"`?

The ? : is a boolean conditional structure (wrong term) it seems but I'm not quite getting it. Don't know what it is called so can't look it up.

Seems something like:

> someBooleanValue ? *if it is false use what is* **before** colon : *else use
>   what is* **after**

I get that it is being used to determine which string to use as the format token (in the code below). I just don't know what this ? : bit is called and what limitations/cautions/abuses there may be with it.

*(and isn't ObjC like `rilly` hard to format in a civilized way)*

```
    UIAlertView* av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hey" 
                                             message:[NSString 
                                    stringWithFormat:@"While %@, I received a local notification: %@",
                                                      inactive ? @"inactive": @"active", n.alertBody] 
                                            delegate:nil 
                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[av show];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ?: thing is called a **conditional operator** or a **ternary operator**.

It's represents a simple condition

```
if ( CONDITION )
    x = a;
else
    x = b;
```

that can be translated to

```
x = CONDITION ? a : b
```

From that you can probably derive the functionality you're trying to accomplish/understand. Keep in mind that, although you could probably use it as a substitute to the normal if/else-if/else structure, it is considered bad programming the usage of the ternary operator out of any "assignment related action".

In [the wikipedia page for it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a) you can find a great variety of examples of the conditional operators used in different programming languages. Check [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operator) too, the ternary operator page.

*Obs: turns out that a ternary operator is not necessarily a conditional expression, but rather any operator that takes three arguments. Since for most of the programming languages the only ternary operator is the inline-if... well, that's what it's usually called.*

Comment: thanks! It doesn't exist in the scripting languages I am used to so while I got the gist, I wasn't sure.

Comment: Note that you can do something like `foo ?: bar;`.  If `foo` is true, `foo` will be the result of the ternary expression, otherwise `bar` will be the result.

Comment: that's supported by only some of the languages that allow ternary operators of the form ?:.

Answer (score 1):

It is called [*conditional operator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a), a kind of *ternary operator* (as opposed to more familiar *binary* `a+b` or *unary* `!flag` operators).

Conditional operator takes a condition, evaluates it, and returns its second or third operand depending on that result.

Answer (score 1):

You can read more information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a).

The use of this operator can greatly reduce code length when a lot of simple `if`s are involved.

Answer (score 0):

It's a ternary operator, but you have it backwards -- if the boolean is true, then do the thing before the colon, otherwise, the one after.

Answer (score 0):

This is called the *ternary operator* and it works exactly the way you described it:

*expression **?** value if true **:** value if false*;

For instance, you could use it for something like this to avoid a if - else:

```
int maxValue = a > b ? a : b;
```

**Edit:** @dasblinkenlight is correct, the operator you're talking about is actually called a conditional operator, which is a kind of ternary operator.